# Turn multiple 2-dimensional arrays into one 3-dimensional array

Tags: r

I'm rather new to R and there's probably a really easy way to do this, but I can not figure this out for the life of me. I am trying to convert a mutli-layer TIF file into a multi-channel TIF file and to do that I need to basically turn a list of multiple 2-dimensional arrays into one 3-dimensional array.

[image]

I attempted to simply split up the 9 different arrays in the list, create a new list with 3 dimensions and insert the arrays into the new list, but it keeps telling me that there is a "wrong number of subscripts".

```
  multiChannelFile = array(c(960, 1280, 9))
  
  for (row in 1:960) {
    for (column in 1:1280) {
      for (channel in 1:9) {
        multiChannelFile[row, column, channel] = tifFile[channel][[1]][row, column]
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `simplify2array()`:

```
multiChannelFile <- simplify2array(tifFile)
```

Comment: Oh, that's a great one-liner. I knew there was an easier way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

And of course, as soon as I posted this question, I figured it out.

Changing `multiChannelFile = array(c(960, 1280, 9))` to `multiChannelFile = array(dim = c(960, 1280, 9))` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can blend the list to a vector by `unlist()` and reset the dimension.

```
array(unlist(tifFile), dim = c(dim(tifFile[[1]]), length(tifFile)))
```